# Empty collection check returning false with no entries (Ruby on Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, collections

I have both a Customer model and Device model, and the Customer model `has_many :devices` and the Device model `belongs_to :customer`. I'm trying to show either a form to add a device on a customer's home page if `customer.devices.empty?` is `true` or simply show customer's device and accompanying details if `customer.devices.empty` is `false`.

My problem is that `customer.devices.empty?` is always returning false. With some tests, I've seen that `customer.devices.count` will always display the correct number of devices, however I only get the desired behavior out of `customer.devices.empty?` while using the Rails console.

I can simply check the value of `customer.devices.count`, but I would really would like to use the `empty?` or `any?` checks as (I think) they are intended.

The problem itself has been described but if you'd like to see code...

```
   <% if customer.devices.count == 0 %>
     Count is 0 <!-- This is displayed on the page -->
   <% end %>
   <% if customer.devices.empty? %>
     Customer has no devices! <!-- This is NOT displayed on the page -->
   <% end %>
   <% if customer.devices.any? %>
     Customer has <%= pluralize(customer.devices.count, "device") %>.
     <!-- The line above prints "Customer has 0 devices." -->
   <% end %>
```

Almost forgot my manners -- Thanks in advance to any and all answers.

-MM

Comment: Have you loaded (but not saved) any devices on this customer?  The `.count` method will always trigger a database query, while `empty?` will not if the association has already been loaded.  Please post the relevant controller code...

Comment: So basically, have I associated a device to a customer (say at some point `@device = customer.devices.build(params[:device]`) without actually performing a `@device.save`? I created a completely new user that, by default, has no associated devices and I realized something strange. I'm using a set of helper functions that let me keep track of the customer across different pages (with a cookie), and the site "home" page that references the helper function, displays the wrong result, whereas if I go to customers/3 it has direct access to the `@customer` variable, and displays everything correct..

Comment: Yup, that explains this behavior.  If you want to see unpersisted data, use the Enumerable methods (`any?`, `empty?`), otherwise use the query API.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use `exists?` instead of `empty?`:

```
customer.devices.exists?
```

The difference is that `exists?` checks the database via the query API, while `empty?` checks the association contents as a standard Enumerable (which may be dirty/modified).

Comment: This works, but if you look at my response to your comment above, why would `empty?` work on the customer's page (i.e. after visiting customer/3 and having direct access to the @customer variable) but not when I'm using a helper function that gets the @customer variable by `@customer ||= Customer.find_by_remember_token(cookies[:remember_token])`?

Comment: @MandM: Where you haven't yet manipulated the `@customer.devices` collection, `empty?` will have no choice but to check the database.  If the collection was already instantiated (via a separate database call, or by manual manipulation as you are doing) it will simply check the collection in its current state.

Answer (score 1):

As per your comment `exists` and `count` will trigger `DB` query to check associated devices. When you use build it is not saved in `DB` so `exists` returns `false` and `count` returns `0`. When you use `blank` it will return `false` that means it has some `devices`

```
customer.devices.blank?
```

Comment: Would like to accept both answers, but Pinny slid in a few minutes before. Thanks!

Comment: `exists?` is slightly more efficient since the database can use EXISTS which is more performant (where available), while `blank?` will call COUNT.  However, both will return the same result.